# Divide Array in subarrays by local peaks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook, sub-array

Hey there i have an numpy array `y` with over 4000 values.

```
data=pd.read_csv('samplesdata.csv',sep=";", decimal=",",encoding='latin-1')
sensor_data=data[['Euklidische Norm']]
sensor_data = np.array(sensor_data).ravel()
sensor_data = sensor_data - np.average(sensor_data) 

# Filter requirements.
order = 2
fs = 100  # sample rate, Hz
cutoff = 1

y = butter_lowpass_filter(sensor_data, cutoff, fs, order)


peaks = find_peaks(y*-1, height = 0.00, threshold = None, distance=170)
height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] #list of heights of peaks
peak_pos = peaks[0]
```

I have an another array with the values local peaks of my array `y` what it calls `height` .

I want to divide the Array `y` in subarrays, but with an condition, that the `height`  should be the borders of the subarrays. Because i want the values between the peaks including the Peaks self.

I want something like, the first subarray should be from the value of first local peak until the value of then second local peak. And the second subarray should be from the second local peak until the third local peak etc.

Has anyone an idea how to solve it, because everything what i tried, i failed.

UPDATE:
[Thats the graph where i need the values from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQZjj.png)

Here are my local peaks.

```
[0.06110087, 0.10401105, 0.07522478, 0.09554681, 0.08982648,
       0.09118464, 0.09309628, 0.10440643, 0.08335122, 0.14826715,
       0.09760258, 0.13332452, 0.11009777, 0.1806636 ]
```

What i need is all values in the graph between my local peaks, like the values between 0.06110087 and 0.10401105 and between 0.10401105 and 0.07522478 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below to subdivise your y array according to the intervals given by your heights (note that your heights array needs to be sorted)

```
import numpy as np

heights = np.array([0,4,8,12,20,30])

y = np.array([1,25,30,7,12])

def subdivise(arr,heights):
    # np.digitize will assign each item in arr to its corresponding interval in heights
    # the right = True is to include the right border of the intervals ( heights[i-1] < x <= heights[i])
    intervals = np.digitize(arr,heights,right=True)
    # The number of subdivisions is the number of the intervals given by the peaks
    subdivision = [[] for _ in range(intervals.max())]
    # assign each element in arr to its corresponding interval 
    for index,bin_pos in enumerate(intervals):
        subdivision[bin_pos - 1].append(arr[index])
    return subdivision

test = subdivise(y,heights)

# Reult from subdivise 
# [[1], [7], [12], [], [25, 30]]
```

UPDATE : for unsorted heights and to include the values of y in all matching subarrays

```
import random

def subdivise(arr,peak_heights):
    intervals = [(min(peak_heights[i],peak_heights[i + 1]),max(peak_heights[i],peak_heights[i + 1]))
            for i in range(len(peak_heights) - 1)]
    
    subarrays = [[] for _ in range(len(intervals))]

    for value in arr:
        for subarray_index,interval in enumerate(intervals):
            if value > interval[0] and value <= interval[1]:
                subarrays[subarray_index].append(value)
    
    return subarrays


### TEST 
peak_heights = [0.06,0.1,0.07,0.09,0.08]

y = [random.uniform(0,0.1) for _ in range(20)]
print(subdivise(y,peak_heights))
```

Comment: The problem is i have a Graph (see update). So i dont want to divide in order because its a graph and not a sequence of values. I want the values between the peaks. Like if i sort the array of `height`, then the second peak is maybe now the fifth peak and the first peak is now the third peak then i would get not the values between the first and the second peak, i would get the values between the third and fifth peak.

Comment: If you height array is not sorted, you will have overlapping intervals, so one value from your y array can fall into two or more intervals. Do you need to append the value the all the corresponding subarrays in that case ?

Comment: Yes, i need all corresponding subarrays in that case.  Sorry i forgot to save the edit. Now you can see my update in my post the graph and why i need it.

Comment: I updated the answer for that case !

Comment: i dont get to values what i need because at the end there are like 20 values in the subarray. I updated my post maybe its more clear what i need.

Comment: its now clear what i need?